# Blender 2.8 - where is "right click" align horizontal/vertical?

Tags: vertices

I just want to change my panels to display horizontally

where is that functionality in blender 2.8 ?

thanks

Comment: You mean the left and right panels in the 3d view? You would like them to be horizontal at the top and at the bottom of the window?

Comment: the content of each window could be displayed horizontally or vertically by doing right click, then choosing horizontal or vertical, the functionality is gone in 2.8

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand:
1) What do you mean when you say: "displayed horizontally or vertically"? How can the content be displayed horizontally or vertically? 2) Can you give a specific example? in which version does it work and where in which point of the window) do you right click to open that "vertical/horizontal" menu?

Comment: (since blender 1.3 maybe) https://i.imgur.com/8D0oXJK.png

Comment: right click on the background on any panel

Comment: [This option has been removed](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/change_log.html#bpy-types-spaceproperties)

Comment: yeah, I am not the only one to say v 2.8 is really a pain in the butt

Comment: The UI has been redesigned for 2.8x and as far as I'm aware there hasn't been a compelling reason to keep the horizontal layout option. You always have the option to use Blender 2.79b, all past versions of Blender can be [downloaded here](https://download.blender.org/release/).